# Connecting to database (phpmyadmin) hosted on website from SQL management studio and/or Power BI

Tags: mysql, sql, web, powerbi

Been searching for a few days now so any assistance with be highly appreciated...

I have a website that has a few forms which collects information from users visiting the site. This information is then written to a database (phpMyadmin) on the site.

I want to use Power Bi and connect to the database to perform some analytics. I have been unsuccessful thus far and ready to hand in the towel.

Steps taken thus far:

1. created a user that can access the database
2. ensured remote access for my machine via Remote MySQL
3. downloaded and installed mySQL Connector

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What does "I have been unsuccessful" means? What happens? Do you get an error? Do you see login dialog when you click Connect in Get data from MySQL? Does your connector match the architecture of Power BI Desktop (32 vs 64 bit)?

Comment: was getting an unable to connect error. figured the issue though...remote sql required my public ip instead of local ip